# Is it possible to more cloud-layers go to different ways on the sky

Tags: atmospheric-science

Sometime when I see the sky I see that the cloud-layers go to different ways. But how is it possible?

Comment: Different winds at different elevations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At different altitudes, speed and direction of wind streams vary. This causes clouds to move in different directions.

Comment: [This wind map](http://hint.fm/wind/) is a wonderful visualization of the wind currents in the US. It does show the variations of speed and direction in the currents.